# Eclipse - Can't see assert outcome in console

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, junit, automated-tests

My Java is quite basic and I am very new to Selenium and I'm testing to see how it works. For some reason in my code, I can see the "assert" outcome in the console, whilst in another part I cannot. I've logged messages to the console before and after the assertation (both of which show) but the assertation result does not.

```
package automationFramework;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class Weather {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "//home//aaronh//Documents//Drivers//geckodriver");
    // System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
    // "//home//aaron//JARs//geckodriver-v0.14.0-linux64//geckodriver");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    // launch browser and go to the website
    String url = "https://www.bbc.com/weather";
    driver.get(url);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    // search weather information for Bristol
    WebElement location = driver.findElement(By.name("search"));
    location.clear();
    location.sendKeys("Bristol, Bristol");

    // click search button
    WebElement search = driver.findElement(By.name("submitBtn"));
    search.click();

    // this assertion fails because it checks the title before the search and IS LOGGED TO THE CONSOLE
    // for
    // Bristol weather has finished

    // String bristol = driver.getTitle();
    // assertEquals("BBC Weather - Bristol", bristol);
    System.out.println("before wait");
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
    if (wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains("BBC Weather - Bristol"))) {
        String bristol = driver.getTitle();
        System.out.println("before assert " + bristol);
// this does not log to the console
        assertEquals("BBC Weather - Bristol", bristol);
        System.out.println("after assert");
    }

    driver.close();
    System.out.println("Test script executed successfully.");
    System.exit(0);

}

}
```

Can someone please tell me why the assertation outputs in one place and not the other? I appreciate the getTitle is pointless because the code won't get these unless the title is what we're asserting but hey, I'm just testing it out.

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't the assert<>(); methods set up to throw exceptions and not to log directly to the console using a system.out.print()-like operation? Anyway, if the assertion fails on the point of assertEuals(), you should not see the "after assert"-sentence at all I believe? Anyway, why not put the stuff you have in main() into a @Test-method instead? :)

Comment: Ah it seems that if the assert fails, it will output to the console (I changed it to compare to "BBC - Weather - Bristoll) and this shows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to distinguish between the **Console** and the **JUnit** view itself.

Example:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    System.out.println("1");
    Assert.assertEquals("A", "A");
    System.out.println("2");
    Assert.assertEquals("A", "B");
    System.out.println("3");
}
```

results in:

A) console output

```
1
2
```

B) [JUnit view](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fref-view-junit.htm) output

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[A]> but was:<[B]>
at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
...
```

Long story short: works as expected; and more importantly: asserts that pass do not create any observable output!