# Show Results/Outcomes Failed Asserts Junit, Cucumber on Console

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, console, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I found this similar [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41978443/eclipse-cant-see-assert-outcome-in-console) but is related to Eclipse, I'm using Visual Studio Code `Version: 1.72.2` on `macOS`.

[image]

Here my `build.gradle` file

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'CursoUdemy'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 13

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-api', version: '5.9.1'
    implementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '4.5.0'
    implementation group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-java', version: '7.8.1'
    testImplementation group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-junit', version: '7.8.1'
    testImplementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-simple', version: '2.0.3'
}
```

I found that is possible to share... but I would like only to see the local Outcomes in my console.

[image]

**Is this related to version of some dependency? In that case... Which?**

**Some clue in order to show the results in my console?**

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/java#_testing
https://www.tapqa.com/html-tables-cucumber-datatables/

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for the parts that can be copy pasted. They're almost impossible to read. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: And try it with `stepNotifications = false`. There is a fair chance this confuses VS code.

Comment: `stepNotifications = false` Is the default value, previos to set the value to `true` I got the same results.

Comment: Then I haven't got a clue. You may have to debug the VS code Plugin or create an issue with them.